# How do I work with an array of swift subclass types?

Tags: ios, swift, types, parse-platform, metaclass

I have a few `PFObject` subclasses that I'm using as models, and I'd like to call Parse's `registerSubclass()` on them in a loop. Here's what I have currently:

```
    let subclasses: [PFObject.Type] = [ 
        Calendar.self,
        Meeting.self,
        UserSetting.self,
        Setting.self
    ]
    for subclass in subclasses {
        subclass.registerSubClass()
    }
```

```

I'm using `Calendar.self` instead of `Calendar` since swift's suggestions say *"use `.self` to reference the type object"*

The problem is that this iterates over **types**, but I need to iterate over **static classes**.

The specific error is `'PFObject.Type' does not have a member named 'registerSubClass'`

How do I make swift iterate over classes, and not types?

---

I have also tried:

```
let subClasses: [PFObject] = [Calendar, ...]
```

but this doesn't work: complains about creating an instance of type `Calendar`

also tried:

```
let subClasses: [PFObject.Type] = [Calendar, ...]
```

but this gives `expected member name or constructor after type call`, and suggests `Use '.self' to reference the type object`, which is how I got to the top approach using `Calendar.self`, `Meeting.self`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you did everything right in your creation of an `Array` of subclasses, and your `for-in` loop is correct as well. Your error is a simple typo. You wrote `registerSubClass` when you meant to write `registerSubclass`. I repeat, this *is* the proper way to work with an array of subclasses.

Comment: Herp derp. Thanks for noticing that.